# How can I exit a loop using a single scanf function that is already taking inputs?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am making a program for some friends and myself that calculates grades with the weighted percentage and what grades need to me made on the final to pass the class with a specified grade.

The for loop in question is this,

```
for(;;)
{
    scanf("%f", &s->grade);
    if(s->grade == 'x')
    {
        break;
    }else{
        grade += s->grade;
    }
}
```

how can I make this exit through the use of a letter rather than a number?
If you need any more code feel free to ask.

Comment: There's a comma in your scanf call, right?

Comment: Read the manual page for scanf as well

Comment: Why not just exit by entering a number outside of the possible grade range (like a negative number)?

Comment: The only time `s->grade` will equal `'x'` is if you input `120` (which is the char code for 'x', naturally.

Comment: @JoelCornett you mean the floating point representation of 120 is the same as the char code for x? I did not know that.

Comment: Yea the scanf has a comma in it haha whoops.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of arguments assigned. Check that!

Comment: @Deduplicator That would cause it to return a 1 which is still in the range of grades which is 0-100

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate input in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556696/validate-input-in-c)

Comment: Where do you get the idea it converts the assigned argument to int and returns that? It already has a perfectly fine place to put it for chrissake...

Comment: I'm sorry I just misunderstood your answer

Comment: @Deduplicator: If you make an answer I will surely upvote. `scanf` does omit all preceding whitespace (unless `%c` is used), then if first non-whitespace character is non-digit (or possibly `+`, `-` sign), then it "fails" and does not read more (in fact such "unwanted" character is given back to `stdin` stream and no futher characters are processed.

Comment: You could check the result of `scanf` and consider any input failure to mean "end of input" , not just specifically `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either check the return value of [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)--`EOF` means nothing was parsed/scanned.

Or, use a two step process. First, read a *string* and check if it equals "x" or whatever, it not, use `sscanf` to convert the string into a float.

Comment: I wanted to avoid a 2 step process was the issue I was having.

Comment: @MackenzieBinns No, you don't want to avoid that, you want to do that, because it's how to solve your problem. Use fgets, check for 'x' and then use sscanf if it isn't 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

You are already asking for a floating point number, and you are checking this against the char 'x', so just replace the 'x' with the value you want or do it in an or.

Comment: The OP wants to know "how can I make this exit through the use of a letter rather than a number?"

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[100];

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) && *buf != 'x')
{
    sscanf(buf, "%f", &s->grade); // should check return value of sscanf to see if the input was correct
    grade += s->grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe that you're asking for a percentage received from somewhere and want to convert that to a letter grade.

If so, I would receive the percentage either from another function passed into the code you have or read from a file.

Then, I would create a switch statement which takes the value received. Truncate it to an int. Then, cast that char you want for the given value. Take that char and bring it into the function you have.

```
Scanf("%f", x);
```

Function(x){
       Switch(x){
            Case 90:
                   (Char*)x = 'a';
                    Return x;
       ...
}